# Find the expected value of the ticket given that it is a winner

Tags: probability

A local sorority is sponsoring a lottery. Each ticket has a value of $W$, random variable taking the values $0$, $10$ or $100$ dollars. The probability of winning $\$100$ is $10\%$ and the variance of $W$ is $73$ times as large as mean.

(a) Find the expected value of the ticket given that it is a winner (either $10$ or $1000$)

This is how I approached the problem.

> $E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=73\cdot \text{mean}$

This is my first equation. My second equation is:

> $\text{mean}=10\cdot x+100\cdot 0.1$

Equating two equations, I get $x$ which is the probability of winning $10$ dollars. I get $x$ to be $.183$. The mean would be:

> $10\cdot 0.18+100\cdot 0.1=11.8$

However, the mean and expected value of a ticket given that it is a winner have different values.The correct value is $40$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your mistake is in your calculation when you equate the variance and the mean. This is what I get
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(W) &= E[W^2] - (E[W])^2\\
&= \sum_{w} w^2P(W = w) - \left[\sum_{w} wP(W=w)\right]^2\\
&=73\cdot \sum_{w} wP(W=w).
\end{align*}

If we let $p$ be $P(W = 10)$ (your $x$), then I got $p = \frac{1}{5}$.

Next, notice that the problem asks for expected value **given** that the ticket is a winner. What you calculated was not this. It was simply the expected value of a ticket.

Notice that you should instead calculate

$$E[W|W=10\cup W=100]= 0\cdot P(W=0|W=10\cup W=100)+10P(W=10|W=10\cup W=100)+100P(W=100|W=10\cup W=100).$$

Doing this, I got $40$.

Comment: Could you please tell me the probability of P(W=10|W=10UW=100)? I know how the formula works but I am not being able to get the probability. Doesn't that expression mean 10*P(W=10 intersection W=10UW=100)? What would be the probability of that?

Comment: Yes! What is the intersection?

Comment: Could you tell me what the probability is?

Comment: The intersection is $W=10$. I think you can figure it out now. By the way, please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Wouldn't I get the same result? 10*P*(W=10)+100*P(W=100) which is the mean i guess?

Comment: $10\cdot P(W=10|W=10\cup W=100) = 10\cdot \frac{P(W=10)}{P(W=10\cup W=100)}$

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great. Good luck.